# Limited number of audio elements on one page in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, jplayer

We're building a language learning game where I need to load a large a
mount of sound files (100+). I'm using jPlayer as my cross-browser
solution. I need to have all the audio preloaded (preload=auto) before
the game can start. The loading doesn't actually take long because each
file is only a few Kb in size.

In all the browsers I'm testing, Chrome, to my surprise, is the only
one that crashes if more than 95 audio files are loaded onto the page.
It gives me the "Aw snaps" message as soon as more than 95 audio tags
are inserted. It is not to do with how many requests are sent at once because
I made sure no more than 20 is in queue at once. So I could have 95
fully loaded audios sitting on the page happily and behaving well,
then if I insert another, it crashes. Interestingly, only Chome on
windows I'm testing are crashing; Chrome on mac works completely fine.

Is anyone else experiencing similar problems? Is there a way around
this or do I have to live with a hard limit on the number of audio
files I can have on one page?

Thanks in advance for answers!

Answer (score 0):

the only thing i can think of are audio sprites...think image sprite, but for audio. although since you have to wait for them all to load, i'm not sure if this is going to help. check it out: http://remysharp.com/2010/12/23/audio-sprites/